# Combinatorics of distinquishable sequences of events

Tags: combinatorics

I have found a problem that I can only solve by guessing, but without any systematic solution:

- 3 distinguishable balls (red, blue, green)
- 5 distinguishable sites (A, B, C & X, Y)

  - X, Y can receive all three balls (one, two, or all three)
  - A, B, C can receive only the blue and the green ball or both

How many ways are there to distribute all three balls onto the sites, if the sequence is important, that is to say the sequence of putting first the red, then the blue, last the green on X, Y and C respectively, if not the same as putting first the green, then the blue, last the red on C, Y and X respectively.

---

My solution:

Construct a tree diagram of three levels for blue, green, red.

For blue and green I have for each all boxes for my choice. Last, the red can only be distributed between the last two boxes X and Y.

I'm getting to 5 (A, B, C & X, Y) [blue] x 5 (A, B, C & X, Y) [green] x 2 (X, Y) [red] = 50.
Due to the sequential importance, I can simply take this number times three to get 150 combinations.

How can I calculate this using combinatorics (factorials and co.)?

Comment: There are 3! = 6 ways to sequence the assignments, not 3.